# Python Selenium return HTML location

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a simple HTML table consisting only of tr/td.
I need to return exact table row , table column number of an exact record.
Solution should be able to handle any number of rows/columns.
To find that item I use:

```
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '8')]")
```

Now I need to return it's location, so far I've been looking into attributes like `value_of_css_property` / `getCssValue` etc. I'm new to selenium, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what you have done so far, _and_ provide any error messages. Why does the expression you provided not work?

Comment: @HunterStevens I need to return exact record location. I have found it by xpath, now i need to know it's exact table row/column location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to locate a row containing a `td` element containing a specific text:

```
element = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[contains(td, '8')]")
```

Or, if you need to locate a specific cell (`td` element):

```
element = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(., '8')]")
```

Then, you can get the [`location`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.location):

```
print(element.location)
```

This would give you the *coordinates* of the element on the page.

---

If you need to get the row and column number of a cell containing the desired text:

```
table = webdriver.find_element_by_id("mytable")

rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
for row_index, row in enumerate(rows, start=1): 
    cells = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")

    for column_index, cell in enumerate(cells, start=1):
        if "8" in cell.text:
            print("Found a match!")
            print(row_index, column_index)
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the location in height or width of the page using the following

```
WebElement needed = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '8')]"); //this puts it in a callable element for you
needed.getLocation().getY(); //this will give the height on the page
needed.getLocation().getX(); //this will give the width on the page
```

But really you're not actually getting the xpath. What you'd be better doing is to find the table you're looking to traverse and do something along these lines.

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("tbody[1]/tr"))
    for (WebElement singleRow: tableRows)/*gets the table rows in a List*/
    {
        List<WebElement> cells = singleRow.findElements(By.xpath("td"))
        for (WebElement singleCell: cells)/*gets the rows cells in a List*/
        {
             trIteratorForRowCount++
             if (singleCell.getText().contains('8'))
             {
                  tdIteratorForCellCount++
                  print (("Total cell is (%s, %s) " % (trIteratorForCellCount, tdIteratorForCellCount))
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as stated in the question I  need exact tr/td not Height/Width

Comment: I considered you might require that and made an edit to my original answer to accommodate you. Sorry my python is a bit rusty but that structure should work for you. I've a feeling @alecxe and I are thinking along the same lines.

Answer (score 1):

I know this task, here is your solution

```
class ElementNotFoundInTable(Exception):
    pass


def find_number(table_content, number):
    """
    returns position of element in the table,
    indexes start from 0

    :param table_content: a content of tbody element
    :param str number: a number to look for in the table
    :return:
    """
    table_content = table_content.strip("<trd/>")
    table_rows = table_content.split("</td></tr><tr><td>")
    for table_row in table_rows:
        if number in table_row:
            row_idx = table_rows.index(table_row)
            column_idx = table_row.split("</td><td>").index(number)
            return row_idx, column_idx
    raise ElementNotFoundInTable("Element '{0}' is not found in the table".format(number))



tbody = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table tbody")
tbody_src = tbody.get_attribute("innerHTML")
find_number(tbody_src, '8')
```